# Ical Expression in Oracle Integration CLoud

Tags: oracle, icalendar, mathematical-expressions, oracle-integration-cloud

For example, Schedule on August 24th, 25th, and 28th, hourly from 8AM to 6PM, respectively. With a biweekly cadence, the following execution would be on Sept 7th, 8th, and 11th, Need 9 days gap between it .

I am trying FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=TH,FR,MO;BYHOUR=8,9,10;BYMINUTE=0;   but it is scheduling every week.

For example, Schedule on August 24th, 25th, and 28th, hourly from 8AM to 6PM, respectively. With a biweekly cadence, the following execution would be on Sept 7th, 8th, and 11th, Need 9 days gap between it .

Answer (score 0):

you may use BYMONTHDAY to list dates with gap of 9 days.